# 10240x768 desktop display

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, display-settings, performance-monitor

I have a lot of small monitors at work; I think they're 1024x768. Is there a device that can take, for example, 10 computer monitors and present it as a single logical 10240x768 display to the computer? I'd like to see if it's possible to make a "tickertape" type of display.

Comment: I'm not going to recommend anything, but I believe that you can accomplish this using one or more video cards in a system that has the appropriate amount of outputs (in your case 10).  Traders are pretty notorious for having extravagant multi-monitor machines.  Search for day trader workstation.  Recommending specific hardware is off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

I misread the question.

You want each monitor to output something different, so what you need is a graphics card which has that many ports on it.  You need to understand what outputs all those monitors supply so that you can choose the appropriate card.  As far as the highest i found was 9

[MatroxC900](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/c-series/c900/)

Comment: He doesn't want to duplicate the display.

Comment: Correct @musselman. I want the multiplexed monitors to appear as one single, logical monitor with a 10240x768 resolution.